# Ruby Array Prints as String

Tags: ruby

This piece of code is supposed to loop through an array of IP addresses and checks to see if a port is open.

```
class Ranger

def initialize(port,file)
    @port = port
    @file = file
    @arr = []
end


def regex(f)
    reg = IO.read(f)
    reg.scan /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/
end


def fileread
        if File.exists?(@file)
            @arr << regex(@file).to_s

            begin
                @arr.each do |ip|
                    sock = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
                    sockaddr = Socket.sockaddr_in(@port, ip.to_i)

                    puts "Host: #{ip}:#{@port} Open" if sock.connect(sockaddr)

                    next

                end

            rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
                false
            end
        end
end
```

end

The code seems to almost completely work, except for one thing. It prints out the success text i.e "Host: #{ip}:#{@port} Open". The problem is that it prints out the entire array where #{ip} is, like this: ["xx.xx.xx.xx","xx.xx.xx.xx","xx.xx.xx.xx"]:22 Open.

It seems to have something to do with the .to_s and .to_i in the script, but it won't work at all without those.

Comment: What output are you expecting? `ip` is an Array, and `@arr` is an Array of Arrays. EDIT: Actually, `@arr` is an Array of String representations of Arrays

Comment: Try `@arr.flatten.each do |ip|` instead. `scan` always returns an array, so `@arr` is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you are only adding ONE thing to the @arr variable...

```
@arr << regex(@file).to_s
```

regex() calls string.scan () which returns an array (presumably your 3 IPs

you're then converting the array to a string and appending the string to @arr.

either you want

```
@arr = regex(@file) # replace
```

or

```
@arr += regex(@file) # concatenate
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. The += operator, as well as removing the .to_s and .to_i fixed the problem.